# Cannot authenticate in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio 2017 trial period has expired, and I am unable to log in to unlock the program. Authentication fails every time, with the error:

```
An error has occurred and we can no longer retrieve information for your account. 
Please reenter your credentials.
```

I checked the logs for the `servicehub`, and they all say (line breaks added for readability):

```
Error : 
  Error starting hub controller: 
    System.InvalidOperationException:
      Controller terminated before accepting connections.
        Exit code: -1073741502.
```

or

```
Error : 
  Exception retrying connect to json rpc: 
    System.InvalidOperationException: 
      Controller terminated before accepting connections.
        Exit code: -1073741502.
```

I have tried running the program as an administrator, deleting the session tokens, using different Microsoft accounts, and even using different PCs. The different PCs issue makes me think that it could be some problem with my network, but I'm not sure what that could be.

Comment: Do you use a proxy server in your network?

Comment: @KenTucker Yes, my workplace does. I'm an intern, and the only developer on-site, so I'm not sure how I would phrase this issue to company tech support to be resolved.

Comment: Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771556.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if you use nodejs on your machine, but I do and a nodejs config thing was totally the underlying issue.  I had added a 'NODE_OPTIONS' environment variable and for whatever reason it apparently wreaks havoc on Visual Studio and other software.

See this article: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/287499/systeminvalidoperationexception-controller-termina.html

Comment: Great! thanks for sharing. Had configured extra memory for nodejs via the environment variables but apparantley VS doesn't like that

Comment: Thank you. Same happened to me as @NicoTimmerman

Comment: Had trouble also with this, not sure if I would have fixed the problem without your info. Thanks!