# "Sorry something went wrong" when installing visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I was attempting to update my Newtonsoft.Json and System.Runtime assemblies in the GAC to 10.0.0 and 4.1.1 respectively, previously they were 3.5.0 and 4.0.0. After that, Visual Studio was unable to start up my previous solutions b/c of an error regarding System.Runtime not being compatible. So I proceeded to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio to fix the issue by using InstallCleanup.exe and run the Visual Studio Installer. InstallCleanup.exe ran successfully, once I began the install process for VS2017 Community, I ran into an error that stated “Something went wrong”.

I then pressed the Report Issue button and it brought up this message:
`` => ERR_PROCESSING_RESPONSE: System.InvalidOperationException: Controller terminated before accepting connections. Exit code: 22 (ErrorStartingServer). at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.NodeHubController.<StartAsync>d__2.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<LaunchOrFindControllerAsync>d__38.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<GetLocationServiceRpcAsync>d__39.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.<WithCancellationSlow>d__9`1.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<LocateServiceAsync>d__41.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceChannelNameAsync>d__26.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<RequestServiceAsync>d__29.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.StorageService.StorageServiceClient.<CreateAsync>d__12.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Feedback.AuthHelper.<CreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Feedback.Communication.CommandHandler.<GetAuthHelperAsync>d__19.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Feedback.Communication.CommandHandler.<OnCheckForSignInCommandImplAsync>d__32.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Feedback.Communication.CommandHandler.<OnCheckForSignInCommandAsync>d__31.MoveNext() — End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown — at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Feedback.Communication.CommandHandler.<OnMessageUiThreadAsync>d__56.MoveNext() ``

I went through the steps listed in these posts, but still having the same issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-uninstall-or-repair/107618

[Error 0x80004003 during VS 2017 RC install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699930/error-0x80004003-during-vs-2017-rc-install/40699948#40699948)

Comment: I looked up the error, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758142/6273251), does that help?

Comment: I looked through that issue and didn't find NODE_OPTIONS on my machine. Thanks for trying @RandomDavis